# Need 12' ladder on second floor but staircase is too tight

Tags: ceiling-fan, ladder

I have a fan on a high ceiling (maybe 16 feet high) that I want to replace. I need at least 12 foot type A ladder but it needs to fold because I have to take it up some tight stairs and corners to get it to the master bedroom.

I tried rending a fixed step ladder from home depot - it weighted a ton and it was so long I couldn't get in in the room.

The telescoping ladders all seem to be 9' tall and I don't want to pay $$$ for a ladder I'll only use once.

Any ideas how to get to that fan?

Comment: I suspect you'll find more uses for a ladder once you've got one - assuming you own the home.

Answer (score 3):

I'd look at renting a tall-ish scaffold set - something like:
[image]
When I'm standing that far off the floor in the middle of a room and wanting to be able to use both of my hands (as I would do when replacing a ceiling fan), I'd like a wide, firm base to stand on.
As long as you can get the individual pieces into the room you want to use it, you assemble it there.

Comment: Seems like substantial overkill for a one time job to me...

Comment: Well, it does until you wake up in the emergency room after the paramedics had fun dragging you down the tight stairs after you fell off the ladder...if you wake up at all.

Comment: Not a bad idea. I'll look into that.

Comment: If that setup is less than a thousand dollars, I need to know where you're getting your stuff at.

Comment: @Mazura - that item in the picture is from [Home Depot](http://www.homedepot.com/p/PRO-SERIES-12-ft-2-Story-Rolling-Scaffold-Tower-with-1000-lb-Load-Capacity-800364/204588148) and is $549 (2017/03/02). Amd I'm suggesting the OP rents it, not buys it.

Comment: I rented a "drywall scaffold tower" just like that last fall to replace a light fixture, it cost me about $30 CAD for a half day. Takes two people about 10 mins to setup (having never done it before) and 5 mins to take down.

Answer (score 3):

A rope, a ladder, and an open **2nd floor window** (you might have to remove both the window sashes). Try not to scrape the side of your house as you pull the ladder up, or if you've an extension ladder, use that to get an a-frame up there. Lay a throw rug on the window frame to protect it.

Option B: hire the job out for less than the cost of a ladder.

Answer (score 2):

Multi position ladders are the bomb.

http://www.homedepot.com/p/Little-Giant-Ladder-Systems-Alta-One-22-ft-Aluminum-Multi-Position-Ladder-with-250-lb-Load-Capacity-Type-I-Duty-Rating-14016-001/202071184

[image]

Comment: So wouldn't that be 11` as an A frame and 22 as straight ladder?

Comment: They do sell multiple model/sizes.  I just linked one example.

Comment: Also: No.  Read the specs.  It's shortest configuration is 5' high.

Comment: They have longer ones, but your are $$$$$. You are probably better renting one.

Comment: Yes - if you're US based, call your local Home Depot ask for tool rental and ask about multi-position ladder availability.

Comment: I rented  a 12 footer from Home Depot but couldn't get it upstairs because it wasn't telescopic. I found extendable one that would work but it's over $400...

Comment: I hate these ladders. They're no fun to stand on and you have to put your shins against the next rung for balance. But +1; answered as asked.

Comment: Some Home Depots do not rent ladders anymore - the Liability is too much.

Comment: @Mazura - I've got one of these at my dad's house: it's fantastic